# How to stop rendering feature points in ARcore with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, archer

I am developing an application action using ARCore with Unity and I want to disable rendering feature points  on the surface through AR camera.

Comment: Can you give more details about your question? Do you mean the feature points? What points are you talking about?

Comment: yes you are right I am talking about feature points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `PointCloudVisualizer` script and disable it that would stop rendering feature points.